# Authorize.net web hook Invalid JSON sent in the Webhook notification

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

I am trying to implement Authorize.net webhook on a Laravel project. From merchant interface, I added a webhook endpoint. But when I try to retrieve events it throws invalid JSON error. What am I doing wrong in the code below?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Anet;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JohnConde\Authnet\AuthnetWebhook;

class xxxController extends Controller
{
    public function webhook(){
        $headers = getallheaders();
        $payload = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $webhook = new AuthnetWebhook(hex2bin('XXXXXD4FF0A6060E23DBCD9AE507E20XXXXX'), $payload, $headers);
        if ($webhook->isValid()) {
            // Get the transaction ID
            $transactionId = $webhook->payload->id;

            // Here you can get more information about the transaction
            $request  = AuthnetApiFactory::getJsonApiHandler('services.authorize.login', 'services.authorize.key');
            $response = $request->getTransactionDetailsRequest(array(
                'transId' => $transactionId
            ));

            /* You can put these response values in the database or whatever your business logic dictates.
            $response->transaction->transactionType
            $response->transaction->transactionStatus
            $response->transaction->authCode
            $response->transaction->AVSResponse
            */
        }     
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
"message": "Invalid JSON sent in the Webhook notification",
    "exception": "JohnConde\\Authnet\\AuthnetInvalidJsonException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/staging/vendor/stymiee/authnetjson/src/authnet/AuthnetWebhook.php",
    "line": 67,
```

Comment: what is the value of `$payload`?

Comment: can you perhaps post line 67 or highlight which line this is? Seems incomplete and it's a bit tough to give advice without that. Speculating on these makes me nervous. What I would try is to output the response of the request instead of calling anything that expects a valid JSON to see what output I'm getting and then go from there to figure out why.

Comment: If you could do a `var_dump($payload);` that would show us what the JSON looks like which would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnConde file_get_contents("php://input"); returning empty value.

Comment: @weaver then that is clearly the issue. the constructor is expecting that argument to contain a valid JSON, not an empty value. you will need to figure out why whatever is triggering the webhook isn't sending json

Comment: i tested my webhook url in webhookinbox.. works fine. but when i am trying to test it with postman getting empty string from file_get_contents("php://input");

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not getting a webhook notification. The code you are using is purposed for validating a webhook notification, rather than making a webhooks request. You have to make a request to get a webhook.

When you set up your endpoint, you can use that code (although I don't think the hex2bin() is required) to validate webhooks and then extract information from them.

To create a webhooks request, you can use code like this-

```
$webhooksArray = array(' net.authorize.payment.authorization.created',' 
net.authorize.payment.authcapture.created',' 
net.authorize.payment.capture.created');
$webhooksUrl = 'https://{yourserver.com}/{your path}/{your endpoint}';

$webhook = new AuthnetAPIFactory();
$handler = $webhook->getWebhooksHandler($login,$transId);
$createWebhooks = $handler->createWebhooks($webhooksArray,$webhooksUrl);
```

This will enroll you in events, which will automatically be sent to your endpoint
i.e `https://{yourserver.com}/{your path}/{your endpoint}`.

Then you can use your code above to validate the webhooks when they hit your endpoint. Once you are enrolled in events and webhooks are being sent to your endpoint, you can retrieve the history using code like this-

```
   $webhook = new AuthnetAPIFactory();
   $handler = $webhook->getWebhooksHandler($login,$transId);
   $history = $handler->getNotificationHistory();
   print_r($history);
```

You can retrieve a specific webhook like this-

```
   $webhook = new AuthnetAPIFactory();
   $handler = $webhook->getWebhooksHandler($login,$transId);
   $webhook = $handler->getWebhook($webhookId);
```

Where $webhookId is the id tied to the webhook you wish to retrieve. You can search through the namespace to see the other method calls for specific webhook actions.

Answer (score 1):

I know, the reply to this question is too late. But I recently faced this issue. I resolved it for one of my projects.

The controller method must have the `Request $request` parameter and the route should be `POST` not `GET`.

The Controller:

```php
class AuthnetWebhookController extends Controller
{
    public function webhookListener(Request $request)
    {
        .....
    }
    // other methods
}
```

The route:

```php
Route::post('authnet-webhook-listener', 'AuthnetWebhookController@webhookListener');
```